# Trained model format conversion with ONNX between Python and Java

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, onnx

From ONNX doc, if I trained a model in Python e.g scikit learn or Pytorch, I could save it as ONNX format, then deploy it in Java runtime production environment.

Is it possible to do in the opposite direction? e.g Train a model in Java, then save it as ONNX format or similar and deploy it in Python production environment?

Comment: In case you are unable to convert a model to ONNX format in Java, Please rephrase the question and title(Conversion of ML model to ONNX in Java) to get solutions for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Any model saved in ONNX format can be loaded in Python production environment using [onnxruntime](https://www.onnxruntime.ai/) package. So if you are able to convert to ONNX format using any language/framework(in this case Java), you can check [this](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/master/onnx/examples/load_model.ipynb) to check how to deploy the onnx model to Python environment.